# refactoring a long function in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this function? And I try to do some refactoring. So with for example a generic function

```
setSelectedSearchOptions(optionLabel: string) {
    //this.filterSection.reset();
    this.selectedOption = optionLabel;
    this.selectedSearch = optionLabel;

    if (optionLabel === 'Registratie') {
       this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.buttonFilterDisabled = false;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.selectedValue = '';
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;
    }

    if (optionLabel === 'Vcheq') {
      this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.isButtonVisible = true;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = true;
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownQrCode = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;

    }

    if (optionLabel === 'Doelen') {
      this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.isButtonVisible = false;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.selectedValue = ',';
      this.selectedValueOptie = ',';
      this.selectedValueProgressie = ',';
      this.showDropdownQrCode = true;
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;

    }
}
```

But seems for me that it can be shorten. But I don't know how exactly.

So my question is, how to make this function shorter?

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of similar assignments inside every `if` just put them out of the condition, and it'll become more readable at once.

Comment: Thank you. but can you give little example will be nice

Comment: Extract common values to outside if statements. You will reduce some lines of code. Also I think that all this logic should be on the template, don't be afraid of using ngIf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the values in a "table" like

```
const LABELS = ['Registratie', 'Vcheq', 'Doelen'];

const OPTIONS = {
                             // Registratie   Vcheq   Doelen
    showDatePickerOne:    [             1,      1,       1],
    showDatePickerTwo:    [             0,      1,       0],
    showDatePickerThree:  [             1,      1,       0],
    ...etc

};
```

and then replace your code with

```
let index = LABELS.indexOf(optionLabel);

for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(OPTIONS)) {
    this[k] = v[index];
}
```

This way you keep the code compact without losing the flexibility.

Comment: Thank you. I try it now

Comment: But I get an error on entries: Property 'entries' does not exist on type '{ showDatePickerOne: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]; showDatePickerTwo: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]; showDateP

Comment: @savantCodeEngineer: anytime ;)

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this:

```
  setSelectedSearchOptions(optionLabel: string) {
    this.selectedOption = optionLabel;
    this.selectedSearch = optionLabel;

    switch (optionLabel) {
      case 'Registratie':
        this.registratie();
        break;
      case 'Vcheq':
        this.vcheq();
        break;
      case 'Doelen':
        this.doelen();
        break;
    }
  }

  private registratie() {
    this.showDatePickerOne = true;
    this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
    this.showDatePickerThree = false;
    this.buttonFilterDisabled = false;
    this.startDate = undefined;
    this.selectedValue = '';
    this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
    this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
    this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
    this.showDropdownIndicator = false;
  }

  private vcheq() {
    this.showDatePickerOne = true;
    this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
    this.showDatePickerThree = false;
    this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
    this.isButtonVisible = true;
    this.startDate = undefined;
    this.showDropdownVcheqCode = true;
    this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
    this.showDropdownQrCode = false;
    this.showDropdownIndicator = false;
  }

  private doelen() {
    this.showDatePickerOne = true;
    this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
    this.showDatePickerThree = false;
    this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
    this.isButtonVisible = false;
    this.startDate = undefined;
    this.selectedValue = ',';
    this.selectedValueOptie = ',';
    this.selectedValueProgressie = ',';
    this.showDropdownQrCode = true;
    this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
    this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
    this.showDropdownIndicator = false;
  }
```

Comment: Just made it more organized, but still have a lot of repeated code.

Comment: Thank you. but I have learned never use a switch case. Sorry, I had to mention this in the post.

Comment: The problem is not repeat assignation of flags. the problem is the logic behing the setting of flags. whe you change the set of flag your component take one behaviour. when you sent other groups of flags change behaviour again. you dont need reduce the code. you need separate the behaviour in clases / functions / etc.  Less lines dont make a better code. single responsavilitie does it.. And you can use switch case like you use a for. a while . do while. if, else etc...